# How to re-write url internally and display correct contents using GET/POST data

Tags: .htaccess

I'm very new to .htaccess and just learning some advanced techniques in php. I am currently working on a php site in the attempt to challenge my skills and i am trying to implement .htaccess to rewrite url for seo friendliness. The difficulty i'm having is that when the user clicks on a language hyperlink, availaible albums' details of that particular language should be displayed, i'm using GET method to post the user selection to the same page (album). I can possibly have separate pages for each language if it is best to do so. by the way i'm hosting my site with Justhost.

normal method:

```
www.site.co.uk/albums - **page** 

<li > <a href="albums.php?selection=tamil/">  TAMIL </a> </li> - **hyperlink** 
<li> <a href="/albums.php?selection=tamil&cat=featured" >Featured </a></li>
```

result: Tamil album contents are displayed ...... this works fine...

what i would like to do for SEO,

```
www.site.co.uk/albums.php?selection=language  **URL to be rewritten**
www.site.co.uk/albums/tamil/    ->>> **Expected result** 

<li > <a href="albums/tamil/"> TAMIL </a> </li> - HTML CODE in album page
```

I would like to use '/' in the URL for separation,if possible. I'm getting 404 error when i click on the 'TAMIL' hyperlink. (custom error page).

please take a look at my current .htaccess that i'm using.

```
 #Use PHP5.4 as default
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php


 RewriteBase /

 # Prevent Directoy listing 
 Options -Indexes

 RewriteEngine On
 # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
 #Options +FollowSymLinks
 Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


 # Specify search friendly URLs
 RewriteRule ^albums/(.*)/$  albums.php?selection=$1


 ErrorDocument 400  /error.php?code=400
 ErrorDocument 401  /error.php?code=401
 ErrorDocument 403  /error.php?code=403
 ErrorDocument 404  /error.php?code=404
 ErrorDocument 500  /error.php?code=500
```

I would really appreciate, yours suggestions, advices and comments and I hope i made myself clear on what i'm intending to do. 
Many thanks to all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-arrange your rules. The rule right above the albums one will get applied first. Try:

```
 #Use PHP5.4 as default
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php


 RewriteBase /

 # Prevent Directoy listing 
 Options -Indexes

 RewriteEngine On
 # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
 #Options +FollowSymLinks
 Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

 # Specify search friendly URLs
 RewriteRule ^albums/(.+)/$  albums.php?selection=$1 [L,QSA]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

 ErrorDocument 400  /error.php?code=400
 ErrorDocument 401  /error.php?code=401
 ErrorDocument 403  /error.php?code=403
 ErrorDocument 404  /error.php?code=404
 ErrorDocument 500  /error.php?code=500
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! it works , so whats the principle behind this?

Comment: The regex for albums is stricter than the rule that adds the php extension. Id the php extension rule comes first, it will just match everything, including requests for album